# How to differentiate arrays of object in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

How can I differentiate if an array is a simple array?

f.e

```
let simpleArr = ["hi","1",3,"5","this is a string",29999]
```

or an array of objects

f.e

```
let objectArr = [
 {el1: "hi", el2: "hi"},
 {el1: "hi2", el2: "hi2"},
 {el1: "hi3", el2: "hi3"},
 {el1: "hi4", el2: "hi4"},
]
```

Is the below enough?

```
const isObject = (obj) => typeof obj === 'object' && obj !== null

isArray(objectArr) && objectArr.every(isObject)
```

Comment: don't forget "function": https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/2f79053d7bc7c9c9561a30dda202b3dcd2b72b90/isObject.js

Comment: If you want to check if *all* members are objects - yes. But this will return `false` when the array contains objects and other data, e.g. `[{}, true, {}]`. Is that expected?

Comment: `const  isSimpleArray = arr => !arr.some(x => typeof x === 'object')`

Comment: @georg yeah, that as well. If you want *any* objects, then you need to include functions as they are also objects.

Comment: @boxdox `[null]` -> `false`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this.

```js
const isObject = item => typeof item === "object" 
                          && !Array.isArray(item) 
                          && item !== null;

const simpleArr = ["hi","1",3,"5","this is a string",29999];
const array_of_objects = [{el1:"hi",el2:"hi"},{el1:"hi2",el2:"hi2"},{el1:"hi3",el2:"hi3"},{el1:"hi4",el2:"hi4"}];

console.log(simpleArr.every(isObject)); // false
console.log(array_of_objects.every(isObject)); // true
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's not a straight forward approach, but you can try doing a deep copy of the Array. You see in javascript comparison between non primitive values like objects will return false even if they both have the exact same properties.

```
{foo: "bar"} === {foo: "bar"} // false
```

```js
const simpleArr = ["hi","1",3,"5","this is a string",29999]
const objectArr = [
 {el1: "hi", el2: "hi"},
 {el1: "hi2", el2: "hi2"},
 {el1: "hi3", el2: "hi3"},
 {el1: "hi4", el2: "hi4"},
]

function deepCopy(array) {
  return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(array));
}

function isSimple(array) {
  const copy = deepCopy(array);
  return array.every((el, index) => el === copy[index]); 
}

console.log("simpleArr:", isSimple(simpleArr))
console.log("objectArr:", isSimple(objectArr))
```

Comment: Don't do that. Too much work and it's prone to failure as you can lose data which can skew your results. https://jsbin.com/zatucuk/edit?js,console

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**, you can do it like so. Just make sure to do a check for `Function` as well.

```js
let simpleArr = [
  "hi",
  "1",
  3,
  "5",
  "this is a string",
  29999,
  Function,
];

let objectArr = [{
    el1: "hi",
    el2: "hi",
  },
  {
    el1: "hi2",
    el2: "hi2",
  },
  {
    el1: "hi3",
    el2: "hi3",
  },
  {
    el1: "hi4",
    el2: "hi4",
  },
];

const isSimpleArray = arr =>
  !arr.some(
    x => x != null && (typeof x === "object" || typeof x === "function")
  );

console.log(isSimpleArray(simpleArr));
console.log(isSimpleArray(objectArr));
```